# Formal semantics of the coordination of tense and modality

Tags: tense, formal-semantics, logic, modality, montague-grammar

There seems to be a good amount of work on the formal semantics of tense, e.g. statements of the form "Dave ate the cookie," and also of modality, e.g. statements of the form "Dave might be at home."

But I've seen next to nothing of the formal semantics of the coordination of these two phenomenon, e.g. "Dave might have eaten the cookie."

Are there resources on this? In particular, the formal semantics of tensed statements with epistemological modality.

Comment: My guess would be they could be treated as modular to one other - separate and can exist compatibly side by side - but some articles seem to discuss that the perfect tense may have some inherently modal qualities, so maybe that interacts with, overlaps with or interferes with other modal words in a sentence

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/book/6000/chapter-abstract/149380848?redirectedFrom=fulltext https://www.jstor.org/stable/25001894 https://www.jstor.org/stable/3840874 https://www.hf.uio.no/ilos/english/people/aca/atleg/perfect_gronn_stechow_oct2017.pdf

Comment: I quickly looked over these and they don’t seem to really address the coordination of tense and modality with regards to truth-conditional semantics. 

I guess what I’m looking for is something akin to Montague’s Coordinate Semantics. That system has some serious weaknesses, and I was wondering if there was any further work on something like it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Saul Kripke’s modal logic, and Angelika Kratzer’s treatment of modality using possible worlds? I originally suggested that in a comment, then removed it when I accidentally thought I had misread the question. I’m sure you can’t do better than this book: https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/40412?login=false Would recommend you see all these articles too: https://oxfordre.com/search?q=Modality&searchBtn=Search&isQuickSearch=true

Comment: I can write up an overview of some modal logic stuff. I would recommend you check out doing logic as a programming language (I know I will be) - trying to write modal logic in the math-programming language Lean Theorem Prover https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/semantics_of_propositional_logic.html (this can allow us to explore what system of logic we feel can accommodate both tense and modality adequately enough to handle sentences like “might have” ! ✅ )

Comment: I’m pretty up to date with contemporary treatments of modality and tense, including Kripke frames for possible world semantics and Kratzed’s work on graded modality and ordering sources.

Comment: Are you aware of what Hotze Rullmann has been doing, e.g. Rullmann, Hotze, and Lisa Matthewson. "Towards a theory of modal-temporal interaction." Language 94, no. 2 (2018): 281-331. doi:10.1353/lan.2018.0018.

Comment: And perhaps Condoravdi 2002 Temporal interpretation of modals?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what the doctor ordered:

> E. Allen EMERSON, CHAPTER 16 - Temporal and Modal Logic,
> Editor(s): JAN VAN LEEUWEN,
> In Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science,
> Formal Models and Semantics,
> Elsevier,
> 1990,
> Pages 995-1072,
> ISBN 9780444880741,
> https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-88074-1.50021-4.
> (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444880741500214)
> Abstract: Publisher Summary
> This chapter discusses temporal and modal logic. The chapter describes a multiaxis classification of systems of temporal logic. The chapter describes the framework of linear temporal logic. In both its propositional and first-order forms, linear temporal logic has been widely employed in the specification and verification of programs. The chapter describes the competing framework of branching temporal logic, which has seen wide use. It also explains how temporal logic structures can be used to model concurrent programs using non-determinism and fairness. The chapter also discusses other modal and temporal logics in computer science. The chapter describes the formal syntax and semantics of Propositional Linear Temporal Logic (PLTL). The chapter also describes the formal syntax and semantics for two representative systems of propositional branching-time temporal logics.

But that one’s hard to get; here an open-access paper:

https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AIIDE/article/download/12836/12683

Their system appears to include time as a primitive type, and something called “Impulse” to handle I believe modality - where modality has something to do with one’s attitudes, perhaps, towards other possible states of affairs, or classes of states of affairs?

> A story encoded in Impulse consists of 6 parts:
>
> - A time basis T , which is a set of intervals
> - An object type hierarchy, which consists of subset defini- tions of a root set O that contains all objects
> - An action type hierarchy, which consists of subset defini- tions of a root set Actions, that contains all actions
> - A set of action properties P , which is a set of functions, mapping from an action to either an object or an interval
> - A set of action instances Σ that make up the story
> - A set of Impulse sentences Ψ that encode additional information about the story

Comment: Code formatting isn't for quotes; I've fixed it up for you.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you